# Scroll grid with buttons- how to prevent button elements from firing while scrolling

Tags: c#, wpf, button, scroll, grid

I have an app in wpf using caliburn micro framework with mvvm pattern which is running in kiosk with touch screen. i want to scroll buttons and when the user wants to click them. I have made grid scrollable inside a scroll viewer but the proplem is that when I leave the touch, it's raising the button-click event. 
Here's the code (xaml) :

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"  x:Name="scroller">
    <Grid  ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True">

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="15"/>
            <RowDefinition x:Name="Row1"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="15"/>
            <RowDefinition x:Name="Row2"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="15"/>
            <RowDefinition x:Name="Row3"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="15"/>
            <RowDefinition x:Name="Row4"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="15"/>
            <RowDefinition x:Name="Row5"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="15"/>
            <RowDefinition x:Name="Row6"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="15"/>
            <RowDefinition x:Name="Row7"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="15"/>
            <RowDefinition x:Name="Row8"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Button x:Name="ViewRedirect1" Grid.Row="1">
            <Image Source="{Binding Path=LeftImage1}" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
        </Button>
        <Button x:Name="ViewRedirect2" Grid.Row="3">
            <Image Source="{Binding Path=LeftImage2}" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
        </Button>
        <Button x:Name="ViewRedirect3" Grid.Row="5">
            <Image Source="{Binding Path=LeftImage3}" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
        </Button>
        <Button x:Name="ViewRedirect4" Grid.Row="7">
            <Image Source="{Binding Path=LeftImage4}" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
        </Button>
        <Button x:Name="ViewRedirect5" Grid.Row="9">
            <Image Source="{Binding Path=LeftImage5}" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
        </Button>
        <Button x:Name="ViewRedirect6" Grid.Row="11">
            <Image Source="{Binding Path=LeftImage6}" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
        </Button>
        <Button x:Name="ViewRedirect7" Grid.Row="13">
            <Image Source="{Binding Path=LeftImage7}" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
        </Button>
        <Button x:Name="ViewRedirect8" Grid.Row="15">
            <Image Source="{Binding Path=LeftImage8}" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
        </Button>

    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

and here is the behind  code about the events

```
private Point scrollStartPoint;

private Point scrollStartOffset;
private DateTime mouseTimer;
private void Scroller_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    mouseTimer = DateTime.Now;

    ScrollViewer scrollViewer = sender as ScrollViewer;
    if (scrollViewer.IsMouseOver)
    {
        scrollStartPoint = e.GetPosition(scrollViewer);
        scrollStartOffset.X = scrollViewer.HorizontalOffset;
        scrollStartOffset.Y = scrollViewer.VerticalOffset;
    }

}

private void Scroller_PreviewMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    ScrollViewer scrollViewer = sender as ScrollViewer;

        if (scrollViewer.IsMouseOver)
        {
            Point currentPoint = e.GetPosition(scrollViewer);

            Point delta = new Point(scrollStartPoint.X - currentPoint.X,
                scrollStartPoint.Y - currentPoint.Y);

            scrollTarget.X = scrollStartOffset.X + delta.X;
            scrollTarget.Y = scrollStartOffset.Y + delta.Y;

            scrollViewer.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(scrollTarget.X);
            scrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(scrollTarget.Y);

        }
}

private void Scroller_PreviewMouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    ScrollViewer scrollViewer = sender as ScrollViewer;
    if (scrollViewer.IsMouseCaptured) { 
        scrollViewer.ReleaseMouseCapture();
    }
    TimeSpan difference = DateTime.Now - mouseTimer;
    if (difference.TotalMilliseconds>500)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

the scroll is goog but when in the button that I leave the finger up, this makes the redirecting

**updated code based on answer below**

Comment: ok done editing, let me know if it works

Comment: I just understood what you meant... (try changing the time to 0.5 sec in my answer) also if you put a breakpoint, you can see the datetime calculated for your small scrolls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement various solutions for this problem,

Look at my answer here, or the authors answer for two separate ways to do it,

[WPF Click Button Scrollviewer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40780980/wpf-click-button-scrollviewer/40781419#40781419)

The solution is with a left mouse click button, but can be adapted for touch,

my way was to use DateTime, to calculate how much time you press, if you are just touching a button, then it would be less than 1second touch, if you are scrolling it would be more than 1 second, so it doesn't raise the button click event

```
private DateTime mouseTimer;

private void Scroller_PreviewTouchDown(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
    {
        mouseTimer = DateTime.Now;
        ScrollViewer scrollViewer = sender as ScrollViewer;
        if (scrollViewer.IsMouseOver)
        {
            scrollStartPoint = e.GetTouchPoint(scrollViewer).Position; 
            scrollStartOffset.X = scrollViewer.HorizontalOffset;
            scrollStartOffset.Y = scrollViewer.VerticalOffset;
        }

    }
private void Scroller_PreviewTouchUp(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
    {

        ScrollViewer scrollViewer = sender as ScrollViewer;
        if(scrollViewer.IsMouseCaptured)
        {
            scrollViewer.ReleaseAllTouchCaptures();
        }

        TimeSpan difference = DateTime.Now - mouseTimer;

              if (difference.TotalSeconds < 1)
               {
                btn_Click(sender, e); //button you want or don't want to rise event
               }
              else
              return;

    }
```

**UPDATE**

Second solution, go to the answer I posted above and use the c# code in the second answer, it is more robust

Comment: it is a very good solution wich worked but the problem now is in small scrolls. in small scrolls the button event still raising. i modified the code like this :  if (difference.TotalMilliseconds>500)
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }   and i changed the touch events with mouseleftbutton events

Comment: @user1654278, so now small scrolls still raise the button event?

Comment: I think you should try the other solution, I think it will work better for you, I'll post the code now

Comment: yes i made this 500 miliseconds. so the solutions is to make testing about an acceptable time

Comment: @user1654278, before playing too much with my answer try the second one as well that uses the InvokeProvider, I actually like it more

Comment: i can see your second answer sorry

Comment: It is in the link I posted in my answer by PCode, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40780980/wpf-click-button-scrollviewer/40781419#40781419

Comment: thanks. i must modify my updated code that is based on your answer